# Does Mathematica know that $\small\frac{\vartheta_3\left(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt[10000000000]{e}}\right)^2}{10000000000}$ not equal $\pi$

Tags: numerics, warning-messages, special-functions, summation

The following is not an identity but is correct to over 42
billion digits:

$$\bigg(\frac{1}{10^5}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{n^2}{10^{10}}}\bigg)^2=\pi$$

I want to check this.

I tried:

```
(1/10^5 Sum[E^(-(n^2/10^10)), {n, -Infinity, Infinity}])^2
```

[image]

I try this, but then I get an error message:

```
EllipticTheta[3, 0, 1/E^(1/10000000000)]^2/10000000000 // N
```

[image]

And this gives a strange result, too (I expected a number):

```
N[EllipticTheta[3, 0, 1/E^(1/10000000000)]^2/10000000000, 10]
```

[image]

Comment: 42 billion digits take at least `N[(Log[2]/Log[10] 42*^9)/(8 1024^3)]` $\approx 1.5$ GB memory to just store. To get a result accurate to this many digits may require a significantly higher working precision.  I'm not hopeful.

Comment: What's so strange about the last result?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I want  only numerical result. not `EllipticTheta[...]`

Comment: I see. I interpreted the result as indicating that further numerical evaluation is not possible (as though it knows there's not enough memory or it surpassed some other internal limit).  I guess it would be nice if there were some error/warning message.

Comment: `EllipticTheta[]` is really not reliable for nomes that are too near the boundary of analyticity ($|q|=1$).

Comment: @Szabolcs on my machine it looks like it would require ~36 GB of memory to compute. I figured this out by extrapolating `Table[MaxMemoryUsed[N[EllipticTheta[3, 0, Exp[-10^-x]]^2 10^-x];], {x, 1, 9}]`.

Comment: That sounds like it is within reach.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake.  That should be `Log[10]/Log[2]`, and the correct estimate is 16 GB, not 1.5 GB.

Comment: This will get you 9 digits and took 36GB: ``EllipticTheta[3, 0, 1.`20/E^(1/10000000000)]^2/10000000000``....just 41999999991 more to go! :)

Comment: I've just evaluated your expression `EllipticTheta[3, 0, 1/E^(1/10000000000)]^2/10000000000 // N` to `3.14159 + 0. I`. It took `35700508792` bytes of RAM.

Comment: Using a [modular identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.7.E32), one obtains the equivalent expression $$\pi\,\vartheta_3\left(0,\exp\left(-10^{10}\pi^2\right)\right)^2$$ The evaluation of that, I'll leave to somebody else.

Comment: The first equation and the first line of code seem to differ.